# How do I connect an Android Emulator to localhost server?

Tags: android, asp.net, azure, localhost

I have an ASP.NET/Azure application running on `http://localhost:4617`. I would like to debug a REST call made from an Android emulator. Related SO threads seem to indicate that you should use `10.0.2.2`. I've tried several variations like `http://10.0.2.2:4617`, but none seem to work. Any other suggestions?

If I do `ping localhost` on my machine, it returns `Reply from ::1: time<1ms` which seems to have something to do with an ipV6 address, but I'm not sure how this is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. If you're running an Azure server-emulator, then you need to run Visual Studio with administrator privileges. If you don't, then it will not bind correctly to the local host.

Answer (score 0):

If the local host is running on your desktop than that is the problem. 
When you type http://10.0.2.2 it tries to connect to the Android emulator local host.

What you need to do is find your computer IP address (you can use google for it). Then once you have it type that into your android emulator browser and it should work

Comment: I can get to my desktop on the emulator using my ip now (it actually goes to the router admin page), but not to the ASP site. How can I connect to port 4617? I've tried http://<ip address>:<port>, but it just times out after like 5+ minutes.

Comment: I am not sure of your setup. However you might need to specify you computer address within the local network. 

Could you elaborate a little more about your setup?